# Firebase not connecting to my android application project

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

#AndroidAppDevelopment
#FirebaseDatabaseProblem

I am developing an app where’s I need to send data from my app to real-time database I have written codes properly using Java ,It’s not throwing any Error but data is not storing in Real-time database in Firebase

I have try to send the data in Real-time database using Java
And I am expecting that to store data into Real-time database In Firebase

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

First Android sturio -> Tools -> Firebase

Rigth side open tab in RealTime database-> Getting start

[image]